# Connecting Tcp Client from one device to Tcp Server in another device

Tags: c#, client-server, ip-address

The Tcp client/server code I'm working with is here: [client](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bew39x2a(v=vs.110).aspx) and [server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te(v=vs.110).aspx).
As the title goes, I'm running the server code on my computer and I want to connect to it from another device using the client code. My question is, to what ip address does my client code have to connect? I know there are many related posts, but I'm only getting information on what's wrong rather than the solution.

Comment: Whatever routable IP address the server has. If you don't know how to find that, open a command prompt on the server and type `ipconfig` and press ENTER. If you're new to networking, you'll want to learn about firewall configuration as well to ensure that the firewall isn't blocking requests on whatever port you're using.

Comment: What exactly is the "routable IP address" in ipconfig? There's the IPv4, IPv6, Subnet Mask, and Default Gateway...

Comment: Whichever IP address the client can get to. Probably the IPv4 address. Does the device only have one network interface? There's usually at least a loopback also. It seems like you'd do well to go through a little network interface 101 training. Read about this stuff. There's tons of material on the internet about it. It's all general theory and not a good fit for an SO question.

Comment: I see two VirtualBox Networks and one Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi 2. The rest are at "Media disconnected" state. Since I'm not using a VirtualBox, I'm left with just the Wireless LAN adapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common problem when developing client/server applications. In a typical home network, there are multiple local IP addresses and a single external IP address. All devices communicating with your network from the outside must use the external IP address. However, when writing client/server applications, if you simply input the external IP address as the address to connect to, you'll quickly discover this won't work.

You need to use Port Forwarding. The client and server will be communicating over a specific port, and Port Forwarding is how your router knows which local IP address to send data to when the client is connecting to the external IP address. You want to login to your router settings, navigate to the section regarding Port Forwarding, and specify that communication over the port you're using in your server should be redirected to the local IP address that your server is running on. Exactly how to change these settings on your router depends on which router you're using.

Run the ipconfig command in a Windows Command Prompt on the machine running your server. Obtain the local IPv4 address from the results. This is the address to use when Port Forwarding the port used by your client/server applications. Adjust your router settings accordingly, and then your client should be able to use your external IP address just fine.

To find your external IP address, any website such as http://www.whatsmyip.org/ should work fine.

If you want to avoid all of these problems for now and simply test your application on your home network, then use the local IPv4 address found when running the ipconfig command on the machine your server is running on. Note that this will only work if both the client and server are running on the same network.

Comment: As you've suggested, I have both the client and the server on the same network. I'm using the local IPv4 address of my laptop (server) so my client should be able to make sense of that address. However, I get this error - WinRT information: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. I'm fairly certain the client does know what server to reach now. What kind of response is expected from the server?

Comment: @Maydayfluffy Hmm. Did you change the code you sent from those links at all? This could be caused by several different things. Maybe print out the IPAddress that the server grabs here: `IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];` and try using that one if it's different than the IPv4? Also make sure both the client and server are set to connect on the same port. Besides that, it could be firewall issues. The port could be in use by something else or your firewall settings could be blocking connections on the port.

Comment: Thank you! It came down to a firewall issue. Disabling it made everything work.